# Kie Server - JAXB error

Tags: jaxb, drools, kie-server

I'm working with a third-party jar for the fact. In this jar there are some interfaces, so when I consume the kie server REST API, I get a JAXB error, the log is at the bottom.
If I try to marshal / un-marshal the BatchExecutionCommand using kie rest api libraries I get no error.
I tried to change the webapps\kieserver\WEB-INF\lib jaxb libraries to the 2.3 versions but the error persists.

Thanks!

```
org.kie.server.api.marshalling.MarshallingException: Error while creating JAXB context from default classes! 9 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    org.kie.server.api.marshalling.jaxb.JaxbMarshaller.<init>(JaxbMarshaller.java:177)
    org.kie.server.api.marshalling.MarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(MarshallerFactory.java:39)
    org.kie.server.services.impl.KieContainerInstanceImpl.getMarshaller(KieContainerInstanceImpl.java:111)
    org.kie.server.services.impl.marshal.MarshallerHelper.marshal(MarshallerHelper.java:47)
    org.kie.server.remote.rest.drools.CommandResource.manageContainer(CommandResource.java:75)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:168)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:541)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:523)
    org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:125)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.kie.server.services.impl.security.web.CaptureHttpRequestFilter.doFilter(CaptureHttpRequestFilter.java:42)
Root Cause: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 9 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
uk.co.portaltech.rulesengine.wrappers.Order is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
    this problem is related to the following location:
```